# Is my work infringing/violating this patent?

Tags: patent-infringement

My name is Steven and i'm based in UK. I wanted to ask if my work on Chrome extension is infringing/violating this patent:[US20130132904](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130132904)or [US8869068](https://www.google.com/patents/US8869068) by any chance?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buttonless/mbpgpedohbkagifgfilmicgklianboei?hl=en-GB

My idea involves around holding down a click and release above on prompted menues. In the patent, it has the same interaction, although it specifically mentioned a radially-distributed menus. What I'm hoping to find out is **does this mean that anything which related to sharing/in browser/ that involves a radially-distributed menus are prohibited or count as infringing this patent?**

Although mine does not look like a pie but it has the same layout displayed in Fig.1 C.

As patent have mentioned these

> As used herein, “radially-distributed” refers to a menu having menu
>   items arranged in a pattern that radiates from a point.
>
> As used herein, “pie menu” means a substantially circular menu made by
>   arrangement of menu items, or “pie slices,” around a central point
>   where selection of a menu item depends on direction rather than
>   distance. In some cases, “pie menu” is used interchangeably with
>   “radial menu.”
>
> Accordingly, a radially-distributed menu has many suitable shapes and
>   sizes. Suitable shapes include, by way of non-limiting examples,
>   substantially circular, semi-circular, partially circular,
>   substantially elliptical, semi-elliptical, substantially ovoid,
>   semi-ovoid, substantially square, substantially diamond, substantially
>   rectangular, substantially triangular, substantially pentagonal,
>   substantially hexagonal, substantially octagonal, and the like.
>   Suitable sizes are generally regulated by available display space and
>   by the number of menu items.
>
> **b. a software module for displaying a radially-distributed menu of
>   destinations for identified content in response to the first user
>   interaction, the menu of destinations allowing the user to select any
>   of: one destination, a plurality of destinations, and all
>   destinations, wherein each destination is a distinct network, forum,
>   service, or application;**

Answer (score 1):

I hate to do this, but your question is so specific that I'm not comfortable answering because you're not a client.

Note, however, that what you've linked to is a patent APPLICATION.  It has not yet issued as a patent.  It might never do so.  You can use something called "[public pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)" from the United States Patent Office to check the progress of this application.

Comment: Hi Ben, Apologise for this specific question. I wasn't sure how I should address it. Many thanks for your help and I confirm that the patent has been issued.

Comment: No need to apologize. I wish i could help, but it seems pretty specific.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refer to Fig 4 and the claims in the granted patent. The [granted patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US8869068) has the limitation

> c. a software module for displaying a radially-distributed menu of
>   individuals associated with one or more displayed destinations in
>   response to a second user interaction, the menu of individuals
>   allowing the user to select any of: one individual, a plurality of
>   individuals, and all individuals;

Your implementation doesn't have a radial menu with a list of people to share the content with, so there should be no infringement.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your time and response. Yes Fig 4 was something that i definitely don't have. I'm more concerned on the side that Fig 1, C has the exact same shape of the way how I present and since the interaction and purpose are more or less the same. It makes me feel very little chance of not infringing this patent. Unless i've missed out something?

Comment: To be infringing, your implementation must include all elements in the claim. Fig 4. is included in the independent claims and is an essential part of the patent, which you don't have and therefore doesn't infringe on.

Comment: Also, a radial menu is a well-known art. A physical dial with various setting arranged radially is a radial menu. There are many software patents on radial menu (e.g. [6,448,987](https://www.google.com/patents/US6448987), [5,706,448](https://www.google.com/patents/US5706448), and [5,790,820](https://www.google.com/patents/US5790820)). Note all the examples contain further improvement on a simple circular menu. The earliest of the three ('820) has already expired. Even if there is an earlier patent on a simple radial menu, it would have expired too.

Comment: Oh so even if it was close but without including all the elements it doesn't count as infringing? Is this 100% genuine that i'm not breaking any laws here? 

The worry i have is that it serves the same purpose.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cortex/decglnkhpfoocpafihfbeodhgofefaoc?hl=en-GB

Comment: No, you wouldn't be infringing because your implementation is just a radial menu, which is well known long before US Pat. '068. The patent owner didn't invent the radial menu. What the patent owner invented is a second radial menu for choosing the designation, which you didn't copy.

Comment: Hi Daneil, many thanks for your clarification and your time again!

Comment: Hi Daneil, i'm looking at 

b. a software module for displaying a radially-distributed menu of destinations for identified content in response to the first user interaction, the menu of destinations allowing the user to select any of: one destination, a plurality of destinations, and all destinations, wherein each destination is a distinct network, forum, service, or application;

and i wanted to ask does this mean anything involves around sharing to a destination with a radial menu is prohibited?

Comment: No. To infringe the patent, you must at least have (b) a radial menu of destination, i.e. Twitter or Facebook, (c) a radial menu of individuals in response to the first radial menu, and (e) a function for customizing the two menus. You can work around the patent by omitting any part. You can also work around the patent by, say, having a second menu of individuals, except that the second menu is a vertical menu, not a radia menu.

Comment: But with my extension, it has sort of a radial menus of destinations, and it was about to be customisable in the settings. So for (b) and (e). Does that mean I either shouldn't have the destination it mentioned specifically like facebook or twitter, not a radial menu and not being able to customise them? Or I display them in a vertical menu?

it says here . 4. (canceled)
5. The media of claim 1, wherein said radially-distributed menu of destinations is a pie menu..  What does it mean if it says canceled? does it mean unlimited of shapes now or not granted patent for this particular shape?

Comment: Another thing that is canceled is "The media of claim 1, wherein said content sharing application is implemented as a web browser extension, plug-in, add-in, or add-on." So this doesn't effect browser extension now? or this affects everything including browser? What I don't understand is, like you said radial menu existed long time ago. so is this patent focused on those radial menu of destinations like fb or twitter to share?

Comment: somehow they've got a second patent? https://www.google.com/patents/US8869068?dq=ininventor:%22Joseph+Primiani%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_1sSBip_MAhUFmBoKHWDGB8kQ6AEIHTAA

Comment: That's the same patent you asked in your original post.

Comment: Similar, because this one is called US8869068 B2 instead of US20130132904 A1. I don't know why there's two, but the claim is different at certain areas.